# Replacing string with special characters in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a large pandas dataframe where one of the columns has weird formatting. I am tring to replace the string, but I keep getting error messages saying: 'error: unterminated character set at position 0'. An example small dataframe is below:

```
col 1    col 2
Amy      [{'?username': 'usr/AMY16548'}]
Jack     [{'?username': 'usr/JACK15822'}]
Sarah    [{'?username': 'usr/SARAH00001'}]
```

Desired result

```
col 1    col 2
Amy      usr/AMY16548
Jack     usr/JACK15822
Sarah    usr/SARAH00001
```

Comment: What is the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?

Comment: Does `df['col 2'] = df['col 2'].str[0].str['?username']` work?

Comment: What's the output of `type(df['col 2'][0])`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Little bit barbaric way, I m sure there is pandas way how to do this, but i dont know it.

```
y=0
for x in df.iloc[:,1]:
    #print (x)
    text=str(x)
    index = text.find('usr')
    df.iloc[y,1]=text[index:-2]
    y+=1
print (df)
```

Comment: I added a proper hard-coded way to do this. Iterating manually over a dataframe is pretty much *never* the best approach when it comes to `pandas`, and throws the whole purpose of `pandas` out the window...

Answer (score 2):

That is because whatever regex pattern that you are using has an opening `[` with no associated closing `]`. Unless you really are trying to use a regex character set (see https://blog.finxter.com/python-character-set-regex-tutorial/), you probably just want to escape the first `[` in your pattern - like `\[`.  Seeing your code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
   col_1                              col_2
0    Amy    [{'?username': 'usr/AMY16548'}]
1   Jack   [{'?username': 'usr/JACK15822'}]
2  Sarah  [{'?username': 'usr/SARAH00001'}]
```

1. Make `col_2` into a python object:

- Note, it's possible that this step can be skipped because they're already python objects~

```
from ast import literal_eval

df.col_2 = df.col_2.apply(literal_eval)
```

2. Now we can access those easily:

```
df.col_2 = df.col_2.str[0].str['?username']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col_1           col_2
0    Amy    usr/AMY16548
1   Jack   usr/JACK15822
2  Sarah  usr/SARAH00001
```

---

If you're going to do it the hard coded way... just do:

```
df['col 2'] = df['col 2'].str[16:-3]
# Same output as above.
```